# Auth0 authorization API for VueJs returning Undefined

Tags: api, vue.js, auth0

I am trying to implement the Authorization API for Auth0 Authorization extension. I followed through the guide here (https://auth0.com/docs/api/authorization-extension?http#introduction)

I was able to successfully get an access_token. 
But when I call the Api with the access token, I only get 'undefined' with a 401 unauthorized error.

The following is the relevant code in my main.js file of the VueJs Application

```
let ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
axios.post('https://georgeprep.auth0.com/oauth/token', config.body, config.headers)
.then(response => {
  ACCESS_TOKEN = response.data.access_token
console.log(response);})
.then(response => {
  const AuthString = 'Bearer '+ (ACCESS_TOKEN)
  axios.get(
  'https://georgeprep.us.webtask.io/adf6e2f2b84784b57522e3b19dfc9201/api/users',
{ authorization : AuthString})})
.then(object => {
  console.log(object)})
```

The image is the response i get in [console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NLIv.png) and the [scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKflN.png) in my API